# IAP needs to refresh View Controller view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, in-app-purchase

I have `ViewController1` and `ViewController2`.

If you go from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`, on `ViewController2` you can buy an IAP that will show a button on `ViewController1`.

VC1 --> VC2, buy --> VC1 (should show button that purchase unlocks)

**The problem I'm having is that the button is not showing immediately on `ViewController1` as soon as I go back from `ViewController2`.**

It only works once I've gone back to `ViewController1` then go forward to `ViewController2` again then go back to `ViewController1`.

**VC1 --> VC2, buy --> VC1 (button 3 still hidden) --> VC2 --> VC1 (button three showing)**

*I'm assuming that refreshes the view somehow, so I'm trying to figure out what can refresh it immediately when I go back to `ViewController1`, instead of having to go back and forth to refresh it.*

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Purchased3"]) {
        buttonThree.hidden = TRUE;
        labelThree.hidden = TRUE;
        NSLog(@"Trying to talk to VC2, hides button/label 3 because there's not purchases");

    } else {
        //buttonThree.hidden = TRUE;
        buttonThree.hidden = FALSE;
        labelThree.hidden = FALSE;
        NSLog(@"Trying to talk to VC2, doesn't hide button/label 3 because there has been a purchase");
    }
```

Thanks for the help, will post more code if needed, or clarify if needed!

**VC1 --> VC2, buy --> VC1 (button 3 still hidden) --> VC2 --> VC1 (button three showing)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that storing the value in NSUserDefaults takes some time, and may not be set when you go back to the ViewController1.

You can solve the issues in 3 ways:

1) When the IAP product is successfully purchased use the [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] API to notify the ViewController1 that it should update itself.

2) You can set a global int property in AppDelegate.h, so you can easily see the newest value instantly (even if it not set in NSUserDefaults yet).

3) Use the Delegation pattern.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `NSNotificationCenter` by adding your `UIViewController` as observer as follow in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateView)
                                             name:@"IAPUpdate"
                                           object:nil];
```

and add that method to view controller

```
-(void)updateView{
    // add your updating view stuff here
}
```

Then in your `UIViewController` where you make a purchase, after purchase, tell the first view controller using notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IAPUpdate" object:self];
```